# How to revert back a specific file to before a specific git commit?

Tags: git

I would like to revert back a specific file to before a specific commit.

I have tried the following (shortened the hash):

- `git checkout 76a843a~1 loginController.js`
- `git checkout 76a843a~1 controllers/loginController.js`

These produce the error:

> error: pathspec 'loginController.js' did not match any file(s) known
>   to git.

Could anyone please advice what I am doing wrong? The file is there, but I am not sure what the path is that git will accept.

Comment: You need to find out the exact file path, maybe by `git ls-tree -r -t 76a843a~1 | grep -i loginController.js`. If it does not exist, you may remember the wrong path.

Comment: I tried that command, but it gives no response/output. It just shows a new line in the cmd

Comment: You could also create and checkout a temporary branch to see if the target file exists in `76a843a~1`, by `git checkout -b temp 76a843a~1`.

Comment: This produces "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout". I could fix this but I am 100% certain the file exists and has not changed path. So I could find the path in the current repository, it would probably solve it (since the path has not changed).

Comment: Its existing in the current repository(revision) does not mean that it exists in `76a843a~1`. If it does not exist in `76a843a~1`, `git checkout 76a843a~1 loginController.js` always fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the revision and the paths with `--`. try:

```
git checkout 76a843a~1 -- loginController.js
git checkout 76a843a~1 -- controllers/loginController.js
```

Or on a single shot:

```
git checkout 76a843a~1 -- loginController.js controllers/loginController.js
```

Assuming it's two different files... either way, make sure to use the right paths (casing and everything).

Comment: I'm afraid this made no difference.

Comment: Ah fixed it! I first had to move up to a different folder, before giving the command